# client side validation and tooltip

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have jsf validation on form where the invalid fields are highlighted based on

```
styleClass="#{component.valid ? 'reportInput' : 'reportInput_invalid'}"
```

and a tooltip is being used for displaying the error message as follows

```
<p:tooltip for="inputFieldId">
    <p:message for="inputFieldId" />
</p:tooltip>
```

Everything works as expected but i want to improve user experience and want to introduce pure client side validation using

```
<p:clientValidator />
```

I tried this but it didnt work when onBlur event is fired on inputfield i got the following JS error

```
'null' is Null or no Object
in validation.js.jsf and the line code is
d.data("uiMessageId",b.attr("id"))
```

Is it possible to achieve?

An example of my input field is:

```
<p:inputText id="bic" 
styleClass="#{component.valid ? 'reportInput' : 'reportInput_invalid'}" 
value="#{bean.bic}" 
required="true" requiredMessage="Field value is required" >
    <p:watermark for="bic" value="CMHJKLIL" />
    <pe:keyFilter regEx="/[a-z0-9]/i" />
    <f:validateLength minimum="8" />
    <p:clientValidator/>
</p:inputText>
```

I am using Primefaces 4 with the following maven dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here as it looks in jsf page head section
[image]

Here is the validation.js file that is being used
[validatuion.js here](http://pastebin.com/TL0PwVJs)

Comment: Please show the code where you are using `<p:clientValidator>` . Without the code we can't help you further.

Comment: I have added the code for one input field.

Comment: You are using `<p:inputMask/>` but I'm not seeing any `mask` property.
Are you sure you want to use `<p:inputMask>` and not `<p:inputText>` ?
**Edit**: I think you have made the changes.

Comment: For this field i don't use p:inputMask, it uses p:inputText, i have edit this.

Comment: Do you have this file `validation.js.jsf`? If yes can you show us the relevent code?

Comment: I have added this, please see the question.

Comment: On Primefaces Showcase it is working, is showcase  based on community version? If it is not then community version seems buggy :(

Answer (score 0):

i had the exact same error.

it seems that the validator.js code searches for a message container attached to the field, and, if cant find one, it searches one in the nearest form "e.findUIMessage(a,d.closest("form").find("div.ui-message"))"

what you need is to have an  tag, 
that is, a message assigned for the inputtext, so, when the validator generates an error, it can post the text in that message container.

Comment: as an examle: <p:message for="bic"/>